# Passive to Active

Tags: passive-voice

The passive voice is,

> Things that should not have been forgotten

I tried converting this to active voice.

attempt 1.

> No one was supposed to forget *those* things.

attempt 2.

> No one was supposed to forget *these* things.

attempt 3.

> No one was to forget those(or 'these'?) things

which one of these, if any at all, are correct?
If none then what is(are) the right one(ones)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to convert the wrong part of the phrase. The passive bit is "have been forgotten". An active rendering of this would be:

> Things that we should not have forgotten.

or if you want to continue using "no-one":

> Things that no-one should have forgotten

but I don't really think that preserves the original sense.